# InkEdit throwing OverflowException on windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-7, tablet

Has anyone had success with fixing this problem with Windows 7 x64 PCs?

Is there any work around for this problem?

Simply creating a new InkEdit object throws an Overflow Exception.

```
InkEdit inkEdit = new InkEdit();
```

throws

{"Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."}

Edit: I did quite a bit of googling but I haven't found any information besides one post where someone suggested changing "specific version" property of the assembly however that didn't work.

Comment: Are you copying local the Microsoft.Ink assembly? You should not be.

Comment: I'm using the latest assembly from the latest Tablet SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the platform target to x86 will get you past that exception (on the build tab of project properties).